# How to interpret the Seasonal Decompose Graphs?

Tags: python, statistics, time-series, statsmodels, arima

**I had implemented seasonal decompose on a series dataset, i.e.:**

```
df1_y.head()

date_time
2010-03-10 18:00:00    2.5
2010-03-10 19:00:00    2.1
2010-03-10 20:00:00    2.2
2010-03-10 21:00:00    2.2
2010-03-10 22:00:00    1.5
Name: target_carbon_monoxide, dtype: float64
```

Seasonal Decopose Code:

```
from statsmodels.tsa.seasonal import seasonal_decompose
x = seasonal_decompose(df1_y, model='multiplicative', filt=None, period=None, two_sided=True, extrapolate_trend=0)
x.plot()
plt.show()
```

**The following graph was displayed:**

[image]

**So can you please tell me, what does the seasonal graph shows? Is it showing any seasonality, or there is no seasonality at all?**

Comment: You should try to resample your values, maybe by day / week.

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your graph is difficult to interpret.
You should resample your dataset (maybe by week / month) or try to focus on a specific period (using mask on your dataframe)